# Is it possible to define default values for union, nested struct and containers in Thrift struct?

Tags: java, thrift

I have a thrift struct which has many fields of different types. Some of them may or may not have default values.

The question is how to define default values in .thrift file?

```
enum E {
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3
}

struct Nested {
  1: i64 f1,
  2: required string f2,
  3: optional E f3 = E.B
}

union Union {
  1: string f1;
  2: string f2;
}


struct TestStruct {
  1: optional E f1 = E.A,
  2: required i64 f2 = 1,
  3: required string f3 = "f3",
  4: Nested f4,
  5: Union f5,
  6: map<string, i64> f6,
  7: set<i64> f7,
  8: list<string> f8
}
```

Considering this example, is it possible to define default values for fields f4-f8?

I assume that it is not possible, but thrift docs does not say it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ConstantsDemo.thrift](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/ConstantsDemo.thrift) file offers some examples, such as:

> ```
> struct thing {
>   1: i32 hello,
>   2: i32 goodbye
> }
> const map<string,i32> GEN_MAP2 = { "hello" : 233, "lkj98d" : 853, 'lkjsdf' : 098325 }
> ```

So the solution could look like so:

```
struct TestStruct {
  1: optional E f1 = E.A,
  2: required i64 f2 = 1,
  3: required string f3 = "f3",
  4: Nested f4 = { f1 : 24, f2 : "i am required", f3 : E.B }
  5: Union f5 = { f1 : "one" }
  6: map<string, i64> f6 = { "hello": 42, "goodbye":24 },
  7: set<i64> f7 = [ 1, 2, 3, -4 ]
  8: list<string> f8 = ["bla","bla","bla"]
}
```

Note that the syntax for `set<>` and `list<>` (brackets) differs from `map<>` (curly braces).

I am getting a strange error with 4 and 5 though ... not sure if that is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-4947) or not.

Comment: Yep, that exactly what i sought! In case of 4 and 5 we need to use similar syntax to map, but specify field names as strings:
`{ "f1" : 24, "f2" : "i am required", "f3" : E.B }`